# PHP using wrong password for SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, access-denied

So I have this SQL query and when I connect the php and MySQL it works but then when I try to run it, the query has an error saying it's using the wrong username/password. But the only place I entered the username and password was when connecting, and then I used the right information and it worked? Here is the code and the error:

```
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect("Correct Host","Correct Username","Correct Password","Correct Database");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

mysql_query("SELECT username, email from Profiles");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Error:

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'wronguser'@'wronghost' (using password: NO) in /home/username/public_html/register.php on line 8

Comment: You make a `mysqli` connection and then to a `mysql_query`, that's never going to work.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! Stupid mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used MySQLi to connect to the database but you used MySQL to run the query. Take note, in PHP, MySQL and MySQLi are different. MySQLi is the newer and improved version of MySQL. So use `mysqli_query()` instead of `mysql_query` since you've connected to the database using MySQLi.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong function to query.  You connected via `mysqli` but then you try and query with `mysql`.  Change your code to:

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username, email from Profiles");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't switch from `mysqli_*` extension to `mysql_*` like that. Use [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/mysqli_query).